# WinJS.xhr local network error

Tags: windows-8, xmlhttprequest, winjs

I am trying to make a simple windows 8 app but I have a problem.
When I try to make a xhr request to a local webserver it fails with the error code: 0x2efd

Sample code:

```js
WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://192.168.0.30" }).then(
    function completed(response) {
        //var json = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
        //var list = new WinJS.Binding.List(json.results);

        console.log(response.responseText);
    },
    function error(error) { console.log(error) },
    function progress(progress) { }
);
```

But when I try a remote IP for instance google.com it works.
What is going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you declare the "private network" capability in your project's application manifest? Double click your application manifest file - It is located under the capabilities tab.

Comment: Also, I had to use an IP for it to work, `localhost` didn't cut it.