# Access intranet portal using Uri Launcher

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8, microsoft-metro

How do I open a webpage by a tile click event in windows 8 grid app? I have tried modifying this event handler but I get an error as it expects a text value.

I have used the following code but it only works if i enter the value manually but  i want it to get the value from the data source.

```
   void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        // Navigate to the appropriate destination page, configuring the new page
        // by passing required information as a navigation parameter
      var itemId = ((SampleDataItem)e.ClickedItem).URL;
    //  this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ItemDetailPage), itemId);

      Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(itemId));

    }
```

UPDATE: so i figured out why it doesnt work, i was pointing to an intranet page link, anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WinJS.xhr local network error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828426/winjs-xhr-local-network-error)

Comment: It worked. Many thanks. Post your answer below and I'll accept it.

Comment: No need for that, just click on the "That solved my problem" button above.

Comment: It doesnt show for me, maybe cause I'm new here..